# How can I determine if my code creates the oExec and nchromePro objects successfully?

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

**How can I determine if my code creates the oExec and nchromePro objects successfully?**
***it show error message in if (Compile Error: Type mismatch)***
Option Explicit

```
Sub Runprofile()
    Dim chromePath As String
    chromePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --profile-directory=""Profile "
    Dim myUrl As String
    myUrl = "https://www.facebook.com"
    Dim intRow As Long, LastRow As Long
    With Worksheets("Data")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For intRow = 1 To LastRow
        Dim myPr As String
        myPr = Range("A" & intRow).Value
        Dim chromePro As String
        chromePro = (chromePath & "" & myPr & """ " & myUrl)
        Dim wshell, oExec As Object
        Set wshell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        Set oExec = wshell.exec(chromePro)
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        Dim nUrl As String
        nUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/checkpoint/"
        Dim nchromePro As String
        nchromePro = (chromePath & "" & myPr & """ " & nUrl)
        If oExec Is nchromePro Then
            .Range("A" & intRow).Font.Color = vbRed
        Else
           .Range("A" & intRow).Font.Color = vbBlack
        End If
    Next intRow
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: oExec is of type Object, nChromePro is a String. The "Is" keyword is a comparison between Objects.

Comment: DS_London please tell me what can i do?  and can you show me some code?

Comment: oExec holds the return information from your call to Exec: here's the reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//2f38xsxe(v=vs.85)  Since I have no way of knowing what you expect the result to be (and hence what might be in oExec), it is hard to help further.

Comment: I want to know my browser run ChromeProflile if condition meet nUrl= "https://www.facebook.com/checkpoint/" change text color in my sheet and another in Else like myUrl= "https://www.facebook.com/" I don't want do anything